# C++ while loop in a custom file structure

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a file called "Players" a simple a.txt file and the code I am using is as follows:-

```
int main()
{
    ofstream theFile("Players.txt");

    cout << " Enters players ID., Name and Money" << endl;
    cout << " press Ctrl+z to quit\n" << endl;

    int idNumber;
    string name;
    int money;

    while (cin >> idNumber **>>** name >>   money) {
                 //       ^^^^^^^^          this
        theFile << idNumber << " " **<<** name << " " << money << endl;
                 //               ^^^^^^^^  and this
        }
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

on the 'while' line and 'theFile' line - the >> marked with `**>>**` keep throwing up an error "no operator '<<' & '>>' supports these operands" - have tried different combinations of syntax without success - the user inputs their idNumber, name, & money the purpose of the while loop is to allow the user to make as many entries as needed and then enters Ctrl+z  to close the file.

Comment: Did you include the header files `<fstream>` (probably) and `<string>` (probably not)? Even though `std::string` may be defined when including, e.g., `<iostream>` it doesn't have to be defined and not all associated operators are necessarily defined unless `<string>` is included.

Comment: thanks Dietmar - advice good - Top Man:)

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly the operators "<<" and ">>" do not support the operands "**" before and after.

Comment: That was just the OP posters way of marking the problomatic part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The above code compiles if you have the correct headers.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
..... etc.
}
```